# Se puede pasar un request http por un endpoint GET?

Tags: java, spring

Quiero hacer una función que me diga si un token sigue siendo válido, pero no sé como pasarle el token desde el front al backend, y no sé si es posible pasarlo así:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/renueva", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Boolean refreshToken (HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        String auth = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        final JWToken token = new JWToken(auth);
        return this.horaDeRenovar(token);
        
    }
```

Comment: Hola Juan, por favor emplea el inglés en todos los casos. Tanto identificadores como nombres de rutas, etc. Además los métodos son acciones, por lo que deben ser verbos, `horaDeRenovar` debería llamarse `renewToken` o algo similar si es lo que hace.

Comment: Ok, gracias, alguna respuesta?

Comment: @PabloRecalde porque deberia usar nombres en ingles? hay alguna condicion programatica para eso? o solo tu gusto? no entiendo tu comentario.

Comment: Alguno quiere por favor pensar en mi pregunta

Comment: No estoy muy seguro si estas utilizando el framework de ```Spring Security``` pero he encontrado un link que  tal vez podría ayudarte: https://blog.softtek.com/es/autenticando-apis-con-spring-y-jwt

Comment: Tu token tiene tiempo de expiración cuando se crea, puedes almacenar ese dato y compararlo con la fecha local y sabes si ha expirado o no.

Comment: @Bicho la función para saber si expiró o no existe, y funciona, perdon por expresarme mal, mi pregunta era mas orientada a: Cómo puedo hacer para pasarle el token al BE, y que este retorne el nuevo token al FE

Comment: Para pasar un token desde el `frontend` al `backend` dispones de muchas opciones, entre las cuales está: Mediante una cabecera http (la cabecera *Authorization* es muy común), mediante una *cookie* (la *cookie* almacenaría el valor del token), mediante una `query` URL (por ejemplo: `http://algunhost.com/ruta?token=<aqui va el valor del token>`), mediante un elemento tipo `input` declarado como `hidden` (o no), mediante un parámetro en la URL (por ejemplo: `https://algunhost.com/ruta/<valor del token aqui>`. En fin, opciones hay muchas. ¿Cuál sería la duda exacta?. Saludos

Comment: Ok, yo lo quiero pasar por cabecera http @MauricioContreras y lo quiero devolver también por cabecera en caso de que necesite un refresh (tengo un interceptor), cómo puedo devolver ese token por http?